# How to make index.html page as an welcome page using Node.js

Tags: node.js, web

I'm a beginner of [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and trying different codes of Node.js. I want to develop a web app in Node.js, and I want its first (welcome page) to be an HTML file. What would example code for it look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a ton of tutorials out there - just google your way to them.

An easy HTTP server example taken from the [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org) website:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

There is also [a great video where Ryan is explaining what Node.js is all about](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=jo_B4LTHi3I).

Also interesting is the [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/index.html) framework.

But get the fundamentals right first.